# Py_InitModule copies the name but not the function pointer?

Tags: python, c++, python-embedding

When I register callbacks using `Py_InitModule`, and if I later change the function pointer in the structure to point to a new function, the new function is called. But if I change the name, the new name is not recognized.

```
#include <Python.h>

PyObject* foo1(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    printf("foo1\n");
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

PyObject* foo2(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    printf("foo2\n");
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

int main()
{
    PyMethodDef methods[] = {
        { "foo", foo1, METH_VARARGS, "foo" },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };

    Py_Initialize();
    Py_InitModule("foo", methods);
    PyRun_SimpleString("import foo\n");
    PyRun_SimpleString("foo.foo()\n");
    methods[0].ml_meth = foo2;
    PyRun_SimpleString("foo.foo()\n");
    methods[0].ml_name = "foo2";
    PyRun_SimpleString("foo.foo()\n");
    PyRun_SimpleString("foo.foo2()\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
foo1
foo2
foo2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foo2'
```

This seems a very inconsistent behavior. I first encountered it when I used a stack variable for `PyMethodDef methods`, which crashed the program once the variable went out of scope and I still tried to call the C++ callback from python. So I tested that changing the pointer indeed changes which function is called even though I haven't re-registered it with another `Py_InitModule` call. But at the same time, changing the name does not have this behavior.

So far I'm pretty certain that `PyMethodDef` needs to live for as long as python code tries to call the methods (i.e. can't be stack/local variable), but only the function pointers themselves are used.

Is this an intentional behavior, or some oversight? The documentation doesn't mention anything about PyMethodDef lifetime that I could find.

Comment: This is expected. What did you think, that the `PyInit_Module` didn't initialize anything? It tells the interpreter which attribute/methods are defined to avoid checking those later. If you want to dynamically rename a function you'd have to 1) obtain the module object from the interpreter 2) Use `PyObject_SetAttr` (or similar, I don't rememeber the exact name) to set the attribute on the module object.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks, but why is the `ml_math` field not copied as well? That is, why does changing it later hot-swap the function to be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inconsistency you see arises from the difference between a function's code, which is the property of the function itself, and the name by which it is invoked from a module, which is the property of the module (key in its dict). While a function's name is also stored in the function object, it is only used for `repr` and is not a fundamental property of the function.

This is quite intentional, as it allows using the same function object in different places under different names - or even without name, if the function is stored in a container. This would not be possible if one could "rename" it just by changing a property of the function.

One can demonstrate this same difference using regular Python functions, like this:

```
>>> def add(a, b): return a + b
... 
>>> def sub(a, b): return a - b
... 
>>> add
<function add at 0x7f9383127938>  # the function has a name
>>> add.__name__ = 'foo'
>>> add                           # the name is changed, but...
<function foo at 0x7f9383127938>
>>> foo                           # the change doesn't affect the module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
>>> add.__code__ = sub.__code__   # we can change the code, though
>>> add(2, 2)
0
```

As for your question in the comment: the method fields are not copied because `Py_InitModule` and related functions are designed to be called with statically allocated structures, creating copies of which would be a waste of space. Not copying them explains why changing the actual C callback in `ml_meth` changes the Python callable.